# regex match between 2 strings

Tags: php, regex, match, preg-match-all

For example I have the text

```
a1aabca2aa3adefa4a
```

I want to extract 2 and 3 with a regex **between** abc and def, so 1 and 4 should be not included in the result.

I tried this

```
if(preg_match_all('#abc(?:a(\d)a)+def#is', file_get_contents('test.txt'), $m, PREG_SET_ORDER))
  print_r($m);
```

I get this

```
> Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abca1aa2adef
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

But I want this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abca1aa2adef
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Is this possible with **one** preg_match_all call? How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You have only one capture group, so group1 will capture only the last `\d`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_match_all(
    '/\d       # match a digit
    (?=.*def)  # only if followed by <anything> + def
    (?!.*abc)  # and not followed by <anything> + abc
    /x', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

works on your example. It assumes that there is exactly one instance of `abc` and `def` per line in your string.

The reason why your attempt didn't work is that your capturing group `(\d)` that matches the digit is within another, repeated group `(?:a(\d)a)+`. With every repetition, the result of the capture is overwritten. This is how regular expressions work.

In other words - see what's happening during the match:

```
Current position    Current part of regex    Capturing group 1
--------------------------------------------------------------
a1a                 no match, advancing...   undefined
   abc              abc                      undefined
      a2a           (?:a(\d)a)               2
         a3a        (?:a(\d)a) (repeated)    3 (overwrites 2)
            def     def                      3
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any solution with PREG_SET_ORDER that shows exactly my desired result? What is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: No, that's not possible because the delimiters `abc` and `def` aren't part of the match - which makes matching more than one number in-between those possible in the first place. I'll edit my answer to show what's wrong with your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You ask if it is possible with a single preg_match_all.

Indeed it is. 
This code outputs exactly what you want.

```
<?php
$subject='a1aabca2aa3adefa4a';
$pattern='/abc(?:a(\d)a+(\d)a)def/m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $all_matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$res[0]=$all_matches[0][0][0];
$res[1]=$all_matches[1][0][0];
$res[2]=$all_matches[2][0][0];
var_dump($res);
?>
```

Here is the output:

```
array
0 => string 'abca2aa3adef' (length=12)
1 => string '2' (length=1)
2 => string '3' (length=1)
```